# Add amount IF statement on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

Please see test file at this
[link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11y6XKY5EkKvYP29oxeTUre-1iSuWkaX3o0MkG8nwwUI/edit?usp=sharing). I have the following formula on a cell:

`=IFERROR(IFS(AND(L5>=60%,L5<=79.99%),J5*132,L5>=80%,J5*150,$L$9>=80%,+2500),0)`

For example, since L5 is 57% (no amt applied) but L9 is at 80%, it should add 2500.

Likewise, cell L6 is at 71% (multiplies amt in J6 by 132 = 660) but L9 is at 80%; it should be a total of 3160 and not 660 by itself.

The formula works perfectly but when it reaches the `+2500` it doesn't add that amount *if* the cell L9 is over 80%. What could be wrong?

---

`=IFERROR(IFS(AND(L5>=60%,L5<=79.99%),J5*132,L5>=80%,J5*150,$L$9>79.99%,M5+2500),0)`

This is giving me a **#REF**!

[image: Pic]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the "if $L$9>79.99% add 2500" as an outer IF:

```
=IFERROR(
  IF(
    $L$9>79.99%,
    IFS(AND(L5>=60%,L5<=79.99%),J5*132,L5>=80%,J5*150)+2500,
    0),
  0
)
```

NOTE: The formula on E5 of the linked spreadsheet returns 0 because there isn't a match on IFS as 57.14% is not included on the IFS conditions. You have to decide if you add a condition to handle L5<60% or to replace the second argument of IFERROR.

Comment: That actually worked! It did add the 2500 to the existing amount, but only on the ones that had $660. It should also add it to the ones that even have $0.

Comment: @A.C. Create a demo spreadsheet including a column with the correct result for each case, share the spreadsheet  with anyone with the link to view only and  add the link to the question.

Comment: Created and added to the question. Thanks Ruben.

Comment: @A.C. added a note to my answer.

Comment: That's awesome Ruben! It works! I was able to handle the L5<60%. Formula ended as =IFERROR(IF($D$8>=80%,IFS(D4<60%,0,AND(D4>=60%,D4<=80%),B4*132,D4>=80%,B4*150)+2500,0),0)

I appreciate it.

Comment: Just found an issue! If D8 is not at or over 80% then all the values end up in $0!

Comment: Was able to fix it. =IFERROR(IF($D$8>=80%,IFS(D4<60%,0,AND(D4>=60%,D4<=80%),B4*132,D4>=80%,B4*150)+2500,IFS(D4<60%,0,AND(D4>=60%,D4<=80%),B4*132,D4>=80%,B4*150)),0) ++++ Thanks Ruben for the help! Kudos!